# Вывод значения из SpinBox в MessageBox

Tags: python, pyqt5, qpushbutton, qmessagebox, qspinbox

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть у меня `Window1`, где есть `SpinBox`, а также есть `PushButton`.

Как сделать так чтобы, при нажатии на `PushButton`, в новом окне выводилось, к примеру "Введено число (значение спинбокса)"

Саму программу прилагаю ниже

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Window1(QWidget):
  def __init__(self):
      super(Window1, self).__init__()
      self.setWindowTitle('Window1')
      self.setMinimumWidth(1000)
      self.setMinimumHeight(800)
      self.btn1 = QPushButton(self)
      self.btn1.setText('Конфигурация первого маршрутизатора')
      self.btn1.adjustSize()
      self.btn1.setGeometry(370,250,250,50)
      self.btn1.show()
      self.a=QSpinBox(self)
      self.a.setGeometry(450, 200, 100,50)
      self.a.setMaximum(255)
      self.lb=QLabel(self)

  def show_window_1(self):
      self.w1 = Window1()
      self.w1.btn1.clicked.connect(self.show_window_2)
      self.w1.show()

  def show_window_2(self):
      self.w2 = Window2()
      self.w2.show()

class Window2(QMessageBox):
  def __init__(self):
      super(Window2, self).__init__()
      self.setWindowTitle('Window2')
      self.setText("ПОМОГИТЕ")


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  w = Window1()
  w.show_window_1()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window2(QMessageBox):
# -------------------> vvvvvvvvvvv <----------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
# ----------------------------------> vvvvvv <------------------------------------------
        super(Window2, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('Window2')
      
#       self.setText("ПОМОГИТЕ")
        self.setText(f'Введено число: {parent.spinBox.value()}')                       # +++
      

class Window1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Window1')
        self.resize(800, 600)
#      self.setMinimumWidth(1000)
#      self.setMinimumHeight(800)

        self.btn1 = QPushButton(self)
        self.btn1.setText('Конфигурация первого маршрутизатора')
        self.btn1.setMinimumWidth(230)
#      self.btn1.adjustSize()
#      self.btn1.setGeometry(370, 250, 250, 50)
# ???      self.btn1.show()
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.show_window_2)                                  # +++         
      
        self.lb = QLabel('Label', alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lb.setStyleSheet('background-color: #D98C00; font-size: 55px;')
      
        self.spinBox = QSpinBox(self)
#      self.spinBox.setGeometry(450, 200, 100,50)
        self.spinBox.setMinimumWidth(230)
        self.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.lb.setNum)
     
        layout = QGridLayout(self)                                                     # +++
        layout.addWidget(self.lb, 0, 0, 1, 2)                                          # +++
        layout.addWidget(self.spinBox, 1, 0, alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignBottom) # +++
        layout.addWidget(self.btn1, 1, 1, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignBottom)     # +++
        layout.setRowStretch(0, 1)                                                     # +++

# ???    def show_window_1(self):
# ???        self.w1 = Window1()
# ???        self.w1.btn1.clicked.connect(self.show_window_2)
# ???        self.w1.show()

    def show_window_2(self):
# ----------------------> vvvv <-------------------------------------------------------
        self.w2 = Window2(self)
        self.w2.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window1()
    
# ???    w.show_window_1()
    w.show()                                                                          # +++
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: расскажи подробнее, что означает строка self.lb = QLabel('Label', alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

Comment: @WPQuesty https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#alignment-prop